# Add a #define in C++ using cmd

Tags: c++, cl

I'm trying to automatically build different flavors of my project.
I'm using the command line to compile the project.
All is working fine but now I want to define a macro in the cml (example : TEST_PROJECT).
I tried using the CL environment variable but it doesn't seem to work
There is an other way to add options to my project
I'm using devenv.exe to compile
devenv.exe project.sln /build
thank you

Answer (score 1):

There's [/D for cl.exe in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). However since you already build .sln file you'll be much better off setting the necessary preprocessor symbol in the project properties. You might want to add a separate project configuration for that.

Comment: The problem is that I have two much configurations right now so I don't want to add a new one
So i'm trying to find a solution without adding more configuration files
thank you for the answer